# How to get user id session in prestashop 1.6.1.3

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

the field name of user id is id_customer and I'm using prestashop 1.6.1.3
I already tried on this

```
 $id = $this->context->customer->id_customer;
```

this

```
$id = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer;
```

this

```
if ($this->context->customer->isLogged()) {

  echo $this->context->customer->id_customer;
}
else{
echo 'Not LoggedIn'; 
}
```

and this

```
   $id_customer = null;
    if ($this->context->customer->isLogged()) {
        // code to execute if i am logued
         $id_customer = $this->context->customer->id;
    }
```

but it's not working ..., can someone help me?
thx

*also if you have a tpl function to get id session, let me know.

Comment: maybe: `$this->context->customer->id;` you could dump out `$this->context->customer` ot even `$this->context` or `$this`

Comment: @Dagon like this?
 $id = $this->context->customer->id;
 echo $id;

Comment: dont ask, if you can just test it.

Comment: @Dagon it doesn't work and make my site broken

Comment: try the other 3 options?

Comment: @Dagon I'll try it again

Comment: `$this->context->customer` and `$this->context` and `$this`
could work but have nothing output

Comment: @Dagon what's next?

Comment: `var_dump($this);` etc

Comment: @Dagon I don't get it, it still don't have an output

Comment: not possible, it will always output something

Comment: @Dagon I also wonder why it doesn't have an output :(

Comment: are you looking at page source?

Comment: @Dagon I run it in tpl and insert it in `{php} {/php}`

Comment: @Dagon do you mean my site? or prestashop site?

Comment: the site the code is running on

Comment: I run the code on the site server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114080/discussion-between-henrikus-anthony-and-dagon).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `$this` which depends of the controller / module you're working with. You can call directly the singleton `Context` object like this:

```
if (Context::getContext()->customer->id)
{
    $id_customer = Context::getContext()->customer->id;
}
else
{
    $id_customer = false;
}
```